# Restoring a Boot Camp image with Windows 7 and making it bootable?

Tags: bootcamp, startup, partition

I have an image of Boot Camp with Windows 7, which was created by Carbon Copy Cleaner. I didn't realize that the image wasn't bootable until I had already deleted the partition.

I'd like to restore the partition with the image, and make it bootable, so that I can return back to where I was before deleting the partition. Is this at all possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make a new Bootcamp partition, download CCC for windows and let it do its job?

Comment: There is no CCC for Windows. If you mean CCC for Mac, then it doesn't restore entire Boot Camp partitions because it won't be bootable; it is only able to restore individual files for a Boot Camp partition. It IS capable of making a bootable Mac partition, though, but that's obviously not what I'm looking for.